# Magento 2.0 vs 2.1: what are the major/breaking changes?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento-2.1, magento-2.0.7

As you may be aware, 2.1 RC1 was released last week as well as 2.0.7 yesterday.

I know 2.1 implies a lot of changes.

My question is, as a developer, **which are the changes I should be aware of and take into consideration** ?

I'm not looking for the release notes, I would like a **list of stuff that changed in the code that are considered as major changes / breaking changes**.

To rephrase it: **which changes should I be aware of when coming from 2.0 to 2.1 developer wise ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CMS, Catalog and GiftCard modules received a major version bump because methods have been *added* to API interfaces:

- Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface
- Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface
- Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductLinkRepositoryInterface
- Magento\GiftCard\Api\Data\GiftcardAmountInterface (EE)

**Source:** https://maxyek.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/2-1-0-rc1-semver-and-major-version-bump/

But this does not count in breaking changes in classes/methods outside the `@api` service contracts.

Comment: Good one indeed and great that they keep going the service contracts route.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about changes(developer wise), one of the major breaking changes I've found is the use of UI Components for the Category New/Edit page. Which means that if you've added a custom attribute to category, it will now need to be specified using an XML file [catalog_form.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.0/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml).

Apparently, this is the way they're going. You can find more details in here. (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5942)

### Edit

Another thing broken in M2.1 is the configurable swatches.  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5691 This was working completely fine in the M2.07

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides a list of backward-incompatible changes on the official dev docs. A list is available for each minor version:

2.0: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes.html
2.1: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes.html
2.2: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes.html

Answer (score -1):

You can read the Release Candidate notes here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1_RC1CE.html

Comment: As I said, I know where the release notes are and that's not what I need. What I would like is a developer wise list of major changes in terms of coding.

Comment: I don't know if there's a reference for that. You could watch commits in the 2.1 branch on github

Comment: Yes I know there's no reference, that's the reason why I'm asking. People with more experience than me with 2.1 may have already found interesting stuff ;)